# Controlar conteúdo de página Javascript de acordo com quem está requisitando

Tags: php, javascript

É possível controlar o conteúdo de uma página de scripts de acordo com com o site que está requisitando esta página?

Por exemplo se o site `X` faz a requisição eu mostro `X` para ser executado, caso o site `Y` acesse eu mostro outro conteúdo dinamicamente. Isso é possível sem que eu necessite alterar o link para cada cliente?

Se for possível como eu faço um array de sites para mostrar `X` e se for o outro `Y` conteúdo?

Comment: Creio que não seja possível, você terá que ter links diferentes, pelo menos um parametro: `seusite.com/?from=outrosite.com`

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que procura? está pouco claro. Dê um exemplo concreto pf.

Comment: Tenho uma página Javascript com diversos códigos dentro dela. Essa página pode ser instalada por vários fóruns mas alguns destes fóruns encontram-se em uma "blacklist" seja pelo comportamento do usuário ou qualquer outro motivo mas ele ficaria impossibilitado de usar o serviço. Só que se eu fizer essa tal "blacklist" via Javascript o cara pode simplesmente baixar o script e configurar de maneira que ele possa usar. O objetivo é esse se o cara usar eu mudo o conteúdo para que ele não possa burlar...

Comment: Infelizmente não será possível, você não pode impedir um usuário de acessar uma página pública.

Comment: Dica: quando estiver falando com alguém nos comentários, use `@nome_do_usuário` para que ele receba uma notificação.

Comment: @Andrey Obrigado pela dica.. Nem havia notado que ali em baixo falava isso. Bom, valeu pelo esclarecimento, acho que vou usar o sistema de parâmetros pela URL caso ninguém saiba uma maneira melhor de faze-lo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma pergunta [bem parecida com a sua](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1153967) foi feita no StackOverflow em inglês. [Uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1154922), que eu traduzirei (pois estamos no SO em português) **de maneira livre** a seguir, está particularmente completa, na minha opinião, e traz as considerações mais úteis para o seu problema.

> Considerando que o cliente (browser do usuário) pode enviar qualquer
>   coisa que ele queira, eu diria que não há como ter certeza de qual
>   site seu script é chamado:
>
> - Uma vez que você quer saber o URL do site que embute seu widget, e não o endereço do usuário, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST']` não ajudará
> - `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` pode parecer OK, mas na verdade não é:
>
>   - O cliente não tem que enviar [*o HTTP_REFERER*] e nem sempre o faz
>   - Como ele é enviado pelo cliente, ele pode ser forjado/falsificado com facilidade
>
> Então, eu diria que não há uma solução real para este problema, pelo
>   menos no lado servidor *(se eu estiver errado, estou interessado em
>   saber!)*
>
> Mas talvez você possa fazer alguma coisa no lado cliente: enquanto
>   estava escrevendo tudo isso, pensei no Google Maps e seu sistema API
>   Key:
>
> - você tem uma chave (única) de API para o seu domínio
> - quando você carrega os scripts JS do Google, você envia esta chave
> - se a chave não é registrada para o domínio do qual você está tentando exibir o mapa, há uma mensagem `alert`, dizendo que "*o
>     servidor da API do Google Maps rejeitou sua requisição. Isto pode ser
>     devido à chave de API usada neste site ser registrada para um site
>     diferente.*"
>
>   - mas o mapa parece ser exibido de qualquer forma -- pelo menos no meu servidor de teste
> - este `alert` é **realmente chato para o usuário final**, e eu não acho que ninguém gostaria de uma mensagem ser exibida em seu site
>     porque estão usando o serviço sem autorização...
>
> Talvez você possa dar uma olhada em como isso é feito no Google Maps
>   :-)